# A href doesnt click

Tags: html, css

I have a href link  ul class name menu it doesnt show post. i dont understand why?

```
 <nav class="navbar js-navbar">
```

```
<li>
  <a href="index.php">Anasayfa</a>
</li>
```

...

but i cant click. Is here CSS Code :

```
     .navbar .menu a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
```

and style.css NAVBAR

```
/* 4.2 - NAVBAR */
.navbar-main {
  background-color: #043140;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 0; }
  .navbar-main ol, .navbar-main li {
    margin: 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700; }
  .navbar-main .nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff; }
  .navbar-main .nav > li.active > a,
  .navbar-main .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-main .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #f6ba18;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .navbar-main .nav .open > a, .navbar-main .nav .open > a:hover, .navbar-main .nav .open > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #f6ba18; }
  .navbar-main .caret {
    margin-left: 10px; }
  .navbar-main .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #043140;
    min-width: 180px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0; }
    .navbar-main .dropdown-menu > li {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #222; }
      .navbar-main .dropdown-menu > li a {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        color: #ffffff; }
        .navbar-main .dropdown-menu > li a:hover {
          background-color: #f6ba18; }
```

Whats the problem here ? I share css or html code if you need it. According to my research its a CSS problem. I have a lot of CSS file. General css file name => style.css also i have a vendor folder and its include reset.css , owl.teheme.default.min.css, owl.careusel.min.css, magnific-popup.css , bootstrap.css and animate.css

Comment: Hi. Can you reproduce the problem in your example code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding z-index maybe it is not on top.

```
.navbar .menu a {
  z-index:999 !important; // just increment or decrement the value.
}
```

Comment: I have seen z-index solution and i try but doesnt work for me.

Comment: Do you have the site running on live? maybe there are some styling that is overlapping your navigation bar. You can use the inspect of your browser and try pointing that navigation bar if there are container style overlapping it.

Comment: Yes i have. You are right. I saw another styling on header.php file. 
.navbar {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #25283d;
}

.navbar .menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  display: flex;
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.navbar .menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

Comment: You can give me the site URL maybe I can help investigate what styling prevents the anchor not clickable.

Comment: This issue is not css :) this javascript is preventing default behavior of anchor because `li` is the parent of anchor. https://prnt.sc/wa65q3